# Unexpected token " in JSON error when scheduling a Cloud function with Google Cloud Tasks

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

Here is my first function which listens for a firestore document to be created and then creates a new Google Cloud Task with the appropriate data.

```
exports.onCreatePost = functions.firestore.document('/posts/{documentId}').onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
const data = snapshot.data()
console.log('data:', data)
const expiresIn = data.expiresIn
console.log('expiresIn:', expiresIn)
//const expiresAt = data.expiresAt

let expirationAtSeconds
if (expiresIn && expiresIn > 0) {
    expirationAtSeconds = Date.now() / 1000 + expiresIn
    console.log('expirationAtSeconds:', expirationAtSeconds)
}
/*else if (expiresAt) {
    expirationAtSeconds = expiresAt.seconds
}*/

if (!expirationAtSeconds) {
    // No expiration set on this document
    return
}

// Get the project ID from the FIREBASE_CONFIG env var
const project = 'project-name'
const location = 'us-central1'
const queue = 'firestore-ttl'

const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient()
const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue)

const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/firestoreTtlCallback`
const docPath = snapshot.ref.path
const payload =  docPath
const body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64')

console.log('payload:', payload)
console.log('payload:', body)

const task = {
    httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        url: url,
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    },
    scheduleTime: {
        seconds: expirationAtSeconds
    }
}

console.log('task:', task)

const [response] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task: task})
console.log('task created:', response)

    })
```

Here is the second function which is supposed to delete the document after a certain time. (Time received from the Google Cloud Tasks)

```
exports.firestoreTtlCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
console.log('Delete callback called')
const payload = req.body
console.log('payload', payload)
try {
    await admin.firestore().doc(payload.docPath).delete()
    res.send(200)
}
catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send(error)
}
    })
```

This is the error I see in the Google Cloud Console after the task calls firestoreTtlCallback

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158)
   at parse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83)
```

I am following this example [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)

I can't figure out what could be wrong with the JSON. I assume it is something to do with what is inside the http request but I don't seem to see anything wrong. Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Response printed from createTask]

Comment: The error is about the JSON but your question does not include the JSON.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hey John, so from my understanding the JSON is created from the data that I have in the task variable. I edited and included a screenshot of what I get when I print out the response from createTask

Comment: The error message is correct. Your picture does not show valid JSON.

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh interesting. So I must be slightly confused because in the example that I linked and in other examples the way that they are creating the task variable and passing it into createTask is the same as how I am doing it here. Am I missing something that would make it valid JSON? This is my first time using Google Cloud stuff so still trying to understand everything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `payload`. It is not a valid json, your payload probally looks like this:

```
const docPath = snapshot.ref.path
const payload =  docPath // a simple string 'some/path/of/document'
```

Try something like follow:

```
const payload = { myPath: docPath }
```